# Prove that there are no positive integer solutions to $y^2 = x^2 + x + 1$ by contradiction.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

I am reading everyone's suggestions, taking notes, and making changes to my proof on paper. I plan on editing later with an update. I really appreciate everyone's help!

I would very much appreciate if someone could verify my proof by contradiction to show that there are no positive integer solutions to $y^2 = x^2 + x + 1$:

*Proof:* (contradiction)
 Assume: $\exists x, y \in \mathbb{Z}^+ s.t. y^2 = x^2 + x + 1$.
 $\implies y^2 = x^2 + x + 1,$
 $\implies 0 = x^2 + x + 1 - y^2,$
    $= x^2 + 2x - x + 1 - y^2,$
    $= (x+1)^2 - x - y^2,$
    $= (x + 1 - y)(x + 1 + y).$

case 1:
    $ x + 1 - y \leq x,$
    $\implies y \leq 1.$

case 2:
    $ x + 1 + y \leq x,$
     $\Rightarrow\!\Leftarrow y \geq -1.$

Hence, there are no positive integer solutions.
$\Box$

Thank you!

Comment: @Aqua Could you elaborate, please? Edit - I see. Case 2 has the same problem.

Comment: @Aqua wow, it's that bad? I'm still pretty new at this.

Comment: For example the very last part is wrong. The statement "$x\ge-1$" is NOT a contradiction to the statement "$x\ge0$". In fact, the former follows directly from the latter

Comment: the usual method is, for $x \geq 1,$  that $x^2 < x^2 + x + 1 < (x+1)^2$

Comment: @WillJagy you're saying that I can choose $x \geq 1$ and go from there?

Comment: For an integer $a$, let there exist $\delta=(a+\varepsilon)^2$ such that $a^2<\delta<(a+1)^2$. Then $0<\varepsilon<1$. Therefore $\varepsilon\notin\mathbb Z$ and so $a+\varepsilon\notin\mathbb Z$. Your question is the special case: $a=x$, $\epsilon=y-x$ and $\delta=x^2+x+1$.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is entirely flawed, because $a=cd$ does not means $a=c$ or $a=d$.

The better proof is here...

$x^2<y^2=x^2+x+1<x^2+2x+1=(x+1)^2$. So $x,y$ cannot be positive integers at the same time.

Comment: I understand your first sentence, but I'm not sure how/where I did that in the proof. I'm putting in several hours a day to understand writing proofs, but I seem to get worse every day. It's very frustrating since I've been making straight A's by learning and understanding over memorizing.

Comment: Let $y=3$, then $y^2-1=8$. if $x(x+2)=8$, then integer solution does't mach $x=y^2-1$ or $x+2=y^2-1$.

Comment: The main part is that since $x > 0$, we can construct $x^2 < x^2 + x + 1 < x^2 + 2x + 1$ just by adding positive things together. Then that leads to $x^2 < y^2 < (x+1)^2$. But that means that $y$ is an integer between $x$ and $x+1$, which is impossible (and which hopefully you have already proved elsewhere).

Comment: @ConMan Thank you! You have helped make things a little bit clearer for me which I greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in a comments, your "solution" is not correct.

You can solve it as quadratic equation on $x$ with integer parameter $y$:$$x^2+x+1-y^2=0$$ Then it discriminant must be a perfect square so $$d^2 = 1-4(1-y^2) =4y^2-3 $$ $$\implies (2y-d)(2y+d)=3$$ Now consider some cases...

Comment: Can you explain why I can multiply by 4? I'm sorry to be a bother, but I'm pretty new and I'm doing my best to learn. I went up through multivariable calc with straight As. But, proofs are kicking my butt.

Comment: @IndiaJ.Delta:  The $4$ is there because the discriminant of $ax^2+bx+c$ is $b^2-\color{red}4ac$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner OMG... That makes sense.

Comment: @Aqua so, I should consider y = 3 for a case?

Answer (score 1):

$y^{2}=(x+1)^{2}-x \implies x=(x+1-y)(x+1+y)$

Then
$x+1+y \leq x \implies 1+y \leq 0 \implies y \leq -1$.

Comment: I think I understand this best. $y \leq -1$ is the contradiction since $y$ cannot be both greater than $1$ and less than $-1$ at the same time. Am I following?

Comment: @IndiaJ.Delta Exactly.

Comment: I have updated my proof. Do you mind looking over it?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that there exists $ x,  y \in \mathbb{Z}^{+} $ that satisfy the equation 
$$ y^2=x^2+x+1$$
Multiplying both sides by $ 4$ gives
$$ (2y) ^2=(2x) ^2+4x+4$$
which is equivalent to
$$ (2y) ^2=(2x+1) ^2+3$$
this leads to
$$ (2y) ^2=(2x+1) ^2+3$$
thus
$$ (2y) ^2-(2x+1) ^2=3$$
hence
$$ (2y-2x-1) (2y+2x+1)=3$$
this implies that 
$$ \begin{cases}2y-2x-1=1 \\ 2y+2x+1=3 \end{cases} $$
this system implies that $(x, y)=(0,1)$. 
Remark: In some countries $0$ is considered as a positive integer, if this the case then  $(x, y)=(0,1)$ is a solution, otherwise a contradiction.